# Add VM-Azure to the domain local

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

how can I add my VM-Azure to the local domain (on-premise server)

any idea?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add Azure VM to your local domain, you need to create a [Site-to-Site VPN Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal) to make your on-premise network can connect Azure Vnet. Meanwhile, you also need to configure custom DNS server on your VM. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://4sysops.com/archives/join-an-azure-vm-to-an-on-prem-active-directory/).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean linking the two networks, on prem and Azure, you can look at this document

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/connect-an-on-premises-network-to-a-microsoft-azure-virtual-network

And if you are looking to join a managed domain you would follow this doc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-join-windows-vm-portal